# Password Field with Asp.Net Dynamic Data

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have a User table that I want to use with Dynamic Data. The Problem is that I have the Password Field that I need to encrypt using MD5. I am Using Entity Framework, How I do this?

Comment: I don't understand the problem, why can't you just encrypt the password and store it in a field on the entity? Like:
var pwd = EncryptPassword(password);
entity.Password = pwd;

Comment: I am using Dynamic Data, I don't have the code that call the Save. But If you know where I its let me know.

Comment: What version of .Net/EF are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution, but If anyone has a better Idea, let me know

```
 public partial class SigecRendicionesEntities
{
   partial void OnContextCreated()
   {
       // Register the handler for the SavingChanges event.
       this.SavingChanges
           += new EventHandler(context_SavingChanges);
   }

   // SavingChanges event handler.
   private static void context_SavingChanges(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // Validate the state of each entity in the context
       // before SaveChanges can succeed.
       foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in
           ((ObjectContext)sender).ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
           EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified))
       {
           // Find an object state entry for a SalesOrderHeader object. 
           if (entry.Entity.GetType() == typeof(Usuario))
           {
               Usuario usr = entry.Entity as Usuario;



               string hashProvider = "MD5CryptoServiceProvider";
               usr.Clave = Cryptographer.CreateHash(hashProvider, usr.Clave);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On alternate idea would be to create a custom FieldTemplate (use UIHint to override the field field template) to encrypt this field.

Comment: I am suing your password Field TEmplate, any Idea How I modified that to do this?